# Import xml file into SQL Server without database (tables)

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, ssms

I have a database which is in XML format contains both structure and data but I don't have database to import the data from XML.

Is there any way to import the XML file into SQL Server, so that SQL Server will read the XML file and subsequently create table structures and insert the data into those tables? Or is there any methodology to convert the XML file into database tables using SSIS services?

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="dbo.AWB_Location_detail" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="dbo.AWB_Location_detail">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Stock_Id" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="LocationId" type="xs:int" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <dbo.AWB_Location_detail>
    <Stock_Id>1</Stock_Id>
    <LocationId>2</LocationId>
  </NewDataSet>
```

Comment: There is no sufficient built-in tool to create a fully strctured database out of an XML - AFAIK... Please show a (reduced) example of your XML...

Comment: hi shungo added the code ...pls review it

Comment: Is there really just one table ("AWB_Location_Detail") with just two columns in this XML? Please add a bit more of your data-section, especially if there is more than one row...

Comment: As you have "StockId" and "LocationId" I'd expect tables for this too...

Comment: I was shared simple format of one table from my xml files of database, ,awb_location_details is transaction table and as you said  those ids are coming from other master tables. or is there any open source software's which will take all xml files and convert them into single sql file .

Comment: How many different "tables" are there? You have one XML for each "table"?

Comment: And - very important: Is this a one.time-action or something you have to do over and over?

Comment: yes ,i have totally 800 XML files for 800 tables , it is one time activity.

Comment: You could write a script task in SSIS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The following is very hacky and will - for sure - not fit to all of your tables...

We need a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #tblXMLTables(TableName NVARCHAR(150),Content XML);
```

With this you can insert one of your files into

```
DECLARE @oneTableXML XML=
(
    SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'F:\test.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS x) AS y
);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xs
                  ,'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata' AS msdata)  
INSERT INTO #tblXMLTables(TableName,Content)
SELECT REPLACE(@oneTableXML.value('(/NewDataSet/xs:schema/xs:element/@msdata:MainDataTable)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'dbo.','')
      ,@oneTableXML;
```

After you have filled all your XMLs into the temp-Table
You can use this code:

Attention: You will have to deal with NULL/NOT NULL, constraints, foreign keys, indexes etc. manually... And this will work with "simple" columns only. If your table deals with more complex structures, you'll have to change the code accordingly...

```
DECLARE @tn NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE tableName CURSOR FOR SELECT TableName FROM #tblXMLTables;
OPEN tableName;
FETCH NEXT FROM tableName INTO @tn;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @columns=
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ',A.B.value(''' + A.B.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') + '[1]'',''' + REPLACE(A.B.value('@type','nvarchar(max)'),'xs:','') + ''') AS ' + A.B.value('@name','nvarchar(max)')
        FROM #tblXMLTables
        CROSS APPLY Content.nodes('//*:sequence/*:element') AS A(B)
        WHERE TableName=@tn
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'');

    SET @cmd=
    'SELECT ' + @columns +
     ' INTO [' + @tn + ']
     FROM #tblXMLTables
     CROSS APPLY Content.nodes(''//dbo.' + @tn + ''') AS A(B)
     WHERE TableName=''' + @tn + ''';'
     ;

    PRINT @cmd;
    EXEC(@cmd)

    SET @cmd='SELECT * FROM ' + @tn;
    EXEC(@cmd);

    FETCH NEXT FROM tableName INTO @tn;
END
CLOSE tableName
DEALLOCATE tableName;
GO

--Clean Up
--DROP TABLE #tblXMLTables;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the xml you want to import is just a .net DataSet object saved as xml. I wrote a quick a dirty .Net library a couple of years ago that will create the corresponding sql tables and import the data via BulkCopy method into SQL Server.

While this is not a pure SQL solution it is relatively easy to implement. The following code example shows how to use the library.

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        connectionBuilder.ApplicationName = "Import";
        connectionBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
        connectionBuilder.DataSource = "(local)";
        connectionBuilder.InitialCatalog = "CodeExamples";
        connectionBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        string connectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\temp\xmlData.xml");

        foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            SqlTableManager tableManager = new SqlTableManager(table, connectionString);
            tableManager.SyncTableSchemas();
            tableManager.UploadTableToSql();
        }
```

I have uploaded the code to File Dropper see link below:

http://www.filedropper.com/sqltablemanagement

Below is a link to a demo application and code.

http://www.filedropper.com/sqltablemanagementdemo

Below is link that demonstrates use for multiple files:

http://www.filedropper.com/sqldatamanagmentdemo2

Comment: I would like to execute all *.xml file under given folder .

Comment: demo is working fine with single  .xml file execution , requesting you to share the full version of sqltablemanagement

Comment: The library provided is the full library the demo just demonstrates the use. I have included an updated version of the demo (dlls only) that will upload multiple files.

Comment: @RajeshPatibandla Hi Rajesh, If my answer works can you, please accept the answer.